# How to increase heap memory of your java application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory

can anyone teach me how to increase your heap size using arguments like ***-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m*** ? What is the difference of Program argument and VM argument?

Answer (score 5):

If you go to Run -> Run Configuration in the Arguments Tab you will find the `VM Arguments` section where you can add this.

Sample Entry in VM Arguments

```
-Xms50M -Xmx128M
```

In `Program Arguments` you mention the arguments which will be passed to the Main Class.

Comment: So which argument will be carried by the jar file? I'm wondering if the jar I am creating retains this max values i set in these argument

Comment: @user2655077 There will be none which will be retained in the jar file that you create.To run your jar you need to pass these params from cmd line. `java -Xms50M -Xmx128M -jar yourjar.jar`

Comment: I think I'm enlightened by that @Ajay George.. ^^

Comment: now my problem is how much memory should i allocate to my app? The server where this app is running has 32G memory..

Comment: @user2655077 that would be a very difficult question to answer without knowing more about your app. Why don't you start by giving it 1G and see whether that suffices.

Comment: i have allocated 2 gb and after few seconds it throws OOM

Comment: try bumping it up to 4 G and enable -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to get the heap dump. Use it to analyze which objects are taking up most memory.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the eclipse.ini file in Eclipse directory.

```
 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130225-1645.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130228-0336
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms1152m
-Xmx1152m
```

and change

```
**openFile
    -vmargs
    -Xms1152m
    -Xmx1152m**
```

accordingly.

Comment: OP is not asking about increasing eclipse's memory.

Comment: Yes but sometimes you need to, to run large apps on Eclipse.

To change it simply go to your eclipse directory and change in eclipse.ini it should work definitely.